# Load balance a database endpoint or produce directly to Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

If my system needs to capture the geolocation of a number of vehicles and record them in a MongoDB, I have two options:
1. Run a server or a cluster of servers on a well known port like 9000 and listen for vehicle messages on it. As soon as a message arrives, the handler will write it to the DB.
2. Run a Kafka cluster which receives the messages and logs them to topics. Another group of servers can then read from the Kafka topics and write to the DB.

From among the above two approaches, is there one that is more preferred?

Comment: Kafka would be preferred simply for persisting that message... For example, what happens when your other service drops a connection to the database? Do you lose the event? Where will you handle the retry logic?

Comment: The vehicle will not communicate to the Kafka directly. The vehicle will send data to a server which receives the data and writes to Kafka. Now the server may also lose connection with the Kafka and the problem will not go away. So what do we gain from Kafka?

Comment: You can push data from Kafka to other systems.... Like Hadoop for machine learning or log collection like Elasticsearch to do anomaly detection.... You could also use NiFi or Streamsets rather than Kafka... My point here is that I would advise you not to write a "one off" service to get external data into a single destination database because you will then need a database export feature or other code to send that data anywhere else rather than use a unified API